# FQL for getting photos from profile pictures suddenly stopped working

Tags: facebook-fql

My app used to get a list photos from Profile Pictures of friends with this FQL:

```
SELECT owner, src_big FROM photo 
WHERE aid IN (
SELECT aid FROM album 
WHERE name="Profile Pictures" 
AND owner IN (XXXXXX,YYYYYYY,ZZZZZZZZ))
```

But now the response is only few photos from ZZZZZ (the last one). Even not all of them are returned.
If I try to delete YYYY,ZZZZ in the list, it works fine, even I'm using IN operator, it returns me all profile pictures of that friend.

Am I missing something ?
Another dev friend of mine tried it too, without success.

Could you guys please try it too in explorer? :)
Thanks!

Comment: I've just found it in bugs section: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/471620432865189?browse=search_4fdcdee00d9982f73644278 if anyone wants to know.

Comment: This is a really helpful post.  Could you clarify the part where it says `owner IN (XXXX,YYYY,ZZZ)` by what you mean by the X,Y,Z?  Are these the authentication tokens or IDs of the users?

Answer (score 0):

I rolled out an App, which went viral, like which grabbed 40k users in couple hours. First it started to not give the profile pics at random times. Then it never worked.

I tried debugging, and caught the errors, and I get `403` when I try to access the pictures.

I assume it is intentional by the FB, or working in a way their 'Spam detection' algorithm would react. Because everytime It happened for me, I soon had an 'App Restriction'.

As a fix, I would say check if your codes are fine and is not making unauthorized calls to Facebook.You wont probably see any errors from the user end, but checkout the `error_log` to see if something's wrong. And make sure you stick to the FB Policies.

My answer may look vague, but it is out of experience. And if its a bug, instead of a `spam prevention feature`, then I am sorry :)